# desabilitar um campo a partir de um valor de select

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5.3

saudações!
estou tentando fazer o seguinte:
no meu campo select tem varios valores dentre eles o outro que só deve ser usado caso o valor não esteja no campo. e um coutro campo de texto que por padrão fica desabilitado e apenas habilita-se caso o usuario clique em outro. tentei deste jeito com Jquery mas sem sucesso. para já conheço muito base de JS e Jquery.
meu script Jquery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#tipo_contac').on('change',function(){
      let tipo_contac = $(this).val();
       if(tipo_contac === '{{$beneficiario->id}}')
                    {
                      $('#outro_cont').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#outro_contac').attr('disabled',true);
                    }
                });
                    
            });
```

parte do formulario

```
 <label>Nome do Contactante</label>

<div class="input-field col s4"> 
    <select  name="tipocontactante_id" id="tipo_contac"  > 
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected default">Seleccione</option>
        @foreach($tipo as $beneficiario)<!-- chama os dados dinamicamente do banco-->
        <option value="{{$beneficiario->id}}">{{$beneficiario->tipo_contactante}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <label>Tipo Contactante</label>   
</div>
<div class="input-field col s4">
    <input type="text" name="empresa_contact">
    <label>Empresa</label>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s4">
        <input type="text" name="contactante_outro" id= "outro_cont" disabled>
        <label>Outro Contactante</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, recomento fortemente você ser como fazer uma pergunta aqui no SO. Outra recomendação é você pesquisar mais antes de fazer uma pergunta. Sua pergunta está muito mal escrita e pouco explicativa, ajude-nos a te ajudar.

Comment: obrigada pela recomendação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar do texto complicado vou tentar ajudar

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#tipo_contac').on('change',function(){ 
     let tipo_contac = $(this).val(); 
     if(tipo_contac != 'valor esperado') {
       $('#outro_contac').attr('disabled', false);
     }else {
       $('#outro_contac').attr('disabled','disabled');
     }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id=tipo_contac>
  <option value=1>oi</option>
  <option value=2>oi</option>
  <option value=3>oi</option>
  <option value='valor esperado'>hahaaaaa</option>
 </select>
 <input id=outro_contac>
```

php pra montar o option:

```
$num_linhas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_query);
for($x=0;$x<$num_linhas;$x++){
  $option = mysqli_result($resultado_query,$x,"Coluna");
  echo "<option value=$option>$option</option>";
}
```

Comment: isso, mas eu tentei colocar no meu valor esperado o id=5 que corresponde ao valor="outro" da minha tabela tipo de forma a que ele possa habilitar o campo de texto e mesmo assim não habilita. só para ressaltar eu estou a trazer a tabela tipo apartir do banco para o formulario

Comment: é só trocar a string "valor esperado" por "outro". Quer ajuda pra montar os options do select também?

Comment: mas eu colocaria a opção "outro" manualmente no HTML e carregaria os valores do banco de dados.

Comment: agradeço a ajuda mas eu prefiro que ele pegue mesmo do banco para o form. espero que exista alguma forma de eu descobrir isso

Comment: alterei a resposta para incluir o que você queria. Olha o final.